# Conky transparency issue

Tags: conky

Good morning,

I am having a issue where my Conky setup will not go transparent. It has a black background no matter what I alter after conducting research. If someone can please assist me it would be greatly appreciated.

```
conky.config = {
    alignment = 'top_right',
    background = yes,
    border_width = 1,
    default_color = '5a5a5a',
    default_outline_color = '5a5a5a',
    default_shade_color = '5a5a5a',
    draw_borders = false,
    draw_graph_borders = true,
    draw_outline = true,
    draw_shades = false,
    use_xft = true,
    font = 'DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12',
    gap_x = 5,
    gap_y = 30,
    minimum_height = 5,
    minimum_width = 5,
    net_avg_samples = 2,
    no_buffers = true,
    out_to_console = false,
    out_to_stderr = false,
    extra_newline = false,
    stippled_borders = 0,
    update_interval = 1.0,
    uppercase = false,
    use_spacer = 'none',
    show_graph_scale = false,
    show_graph_range = false,
    own_window = true,
    own_window_class = 'Conky',
    own_window_type = 'normal',
    own_window_hints = 'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
    own_window_transparent = yes,
    own_window_argb_visual = yes,
    own_window_color = '5a5a5a',
    own_window_argb_value = 175
}
```

Comment: This page suggests you should have `own_window_type='desktop'` https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/conky#Transparency but posting as comment because I'm terrified of trying it and messing up my working config.

Answer (score 1):

This is my Conky (1.11.6) config which is transparent on Ubuntu 20.10 desktop. I think `background` and `own_window_type` are the most relevant:

```
conky.config = {
    alignment                           = 'top_left',
    background                          = false,
    border_inner_margin                 = 0,
    border_outer_margin                 = 0,
    border_width                        = 0,
    color0                              = '1FAAF0',
    color1                              = 'EBE1E1',
    cpu_avg_samples                     = 2,
    default_color                       = 'gray',
    default_outline_color               = 'green',
    default_shade_color                 = 'red',
    diskio_avg_samples                  = 2,
    double_buffer                       = true,
    draw_borders                        = false,
    draw_graph_borders                  = false,
    draw_outline                        = false,
    draw_shades                         = false,
    extra_newline                       = false,
    font                                = 'Play:normal:size=7',
    format_human_readable               = true,
    gap_x                               = 150,
    gap_y                               = 50,
    lua_load                            = '/home/me/rings.lua',
    lua_draw_hook_pre                   = 'conky_main',
    maximum_width                       = 1920,
    minimum_width                       = 1920,
    net_avg_samples                     = 2,
    no_buffers                          = true,
    out_to_console                      = false,
    out_to_stderr                       = false,
    extra_newline                       = false,
    own_window                          = true,
    own_window_argb_visual              = true,
    own_window_class                    = 'Conky',
    own_window_type                     = 'desktop',
    own_window_transparent              = true,
    own_window_argb_visual              = true,
    override_utf8_locale                = true,
    stippled_borders                    = 0,
    temperature_unit                    = 'celsius',
    text_buffer_size                    = 2048,
    update_interval                     = 1.0,
    uppercase                           = false,
    use_spacer                          = 'none',
    use_xft                             = true,
    show_graph_scale                    = false,
    show_graph_range                    = false,
    xftalpha                            = 0.9,
};
```